# Promise.all with axios / node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, axios

I am a bit stuck here trying to wait for results from two or more axios promises to process them further. console.log("test"); is being executed before the other method calls have been fully executed. I feel how I setup the recursive parsing isn't correct but not sure what to adjust. Anyone here has an idea? Thank you so much.

Output ---

```
test
Mon Sep 14 2020 14:04:37 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time) - 2020-09-13T00:00:00Z - 2020-09-14T00:00:00Z - 0 - 14897 - 1000
Mon Sep 14 2020 14:04:37 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time) - 6 - 3247395
```

index ---

```
Promise.all([
  vault.collectAuditTrailHistory('document_audit_trail', startDate, endDate),
  vault.collectGroupMembers(6)
]).then(result => {
  console.log("test");
})
```

vault class ---

```
async login() {
        return this.axiosInstance
            .post('/api/v20.2/auth', 'username=' + this.username + '&password=' + this.password, this.config)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.responseStatus = "SUCCESS") {
                    this.axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.sessionId;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }

    async collectAuditTrailHistory(audittrail, startDate, endDate) {
        // check valid login
        if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
            return this.axiosInstance
                .get('/api/v20.2/audittrail/'+ audittrail +'?start_date=' + startDate + '&end_date=' + endDate + '&limit=1', this.config)
                .then(response => {
                    this.parseAuditTrailHistoryPage(audittrail, startDate, endDate, 0, response.data.responseDetails.total, 1000);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        } else {
            return this.login()
                .then((response) => {
                    this.collectAuditTrailHistory(audittrail, startDate, endDate);
                });
        }
    }

    async collectGroupMembers(groudId) {
        // check valid login
        if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
            return this.axiosInstance
                .get('/api/v20.2/objects/groups/' + groudId, this.config)
                .then(response => {
                    for(let i = 0; i < response.data.groups[0].group.members__v.length; i++){ 
                        this.collectUserName(groudId, response.data.groups[0].group.members__v[i]);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        } else {
            return this.login()
                .then((response) => {
                    return this.collectGroupMembers(groudId);
                });
        }
    }

    async collectUserName(groudId, userId) {
        // check valid login
        if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
            return this.axiosInstance
                .get('/api/v20.2/objects/users/' + userId, this.config)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(new Date() + " - " + groudId + " - " + userId);
                    this.groupMembers.push([groudId,response.data.users[0].user.user_name__v]);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        } else {
            return this.login()
                .then((response) => {
                    return this.collectUserName(groudId, userId);
                });
        }
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        if (!this.axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] || !this.lastTxnDateTime)
            return false;
        else {
            let diff = Math.abs(new Date() - this.lastTxnDateTime);
            if (Math.floor((diff/1000)/60) < 15) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    async parseAuditTrailHistoryPage(audittrail, startDate, endDate, offset, total, limit) {
        console.log(new Date() + " - " + startDate + " - " + endDate + " - " + offset + " - " + total + " - " + limit);
        return this.axiosInstance
            .get('/api/v20.2/audittrail/' + audittrail + '?start_date=' + startDate + '&end_date=' + endDate + '&limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset, this.config)
            .then(response => {
                if ((offset+limit) < total) {
                    this.auditTrailHistory = this.auditTrailHistory.concat(response.data.data);
                    this.parseAuditTrailHistoryPage(audittrail, startDate, endDate, (offset+limit+1), total, limit);                    
                }
                else {
                    this.auditTrailHistory = this.auditTrailHistory.concat(response.data.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your missing some `return` in you `then`.

```
    async parseAuditTrailHistoryPage(audittrail, startDate, endDate, offset, total, limit) {
        console.log(new Date() + " - " + startDate + " - " + endDate + " - " + offset + " - " + total + " - " + limit);
        return this.axiosInstance
            .get('/api/v20.2/audittrail/' + audittrail + '?start_date=' + startDate + '&end_date=' + endDate + '&limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset, this.config)
            .then(response => {
                if ((offset+limit) < total) {
                    this.auditTrailHistory = this.auditTrailHistory.concat(response.data.data);

                    // return promise (add it to the end of the  promise chaine)
                    return this.parseAuditTrailHistoryPage(audittrail, startDate, endDate, (offset+limit+1), total, limit);                    
                }
                else {
                    this.auditTrailHistory = this.auditTrailHistory.concat(response.data.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

Without the fix the `parseAuditTrailHistoryPage` will not wait for the internal `parseAuditTrailHistoryPage` to resolve. With the fix, each iteration of the recursion will wait for the next one till the last one (when `(offset+limit) < total == false)`.

Same issue in `collectUserName`, `collectAuditTrailHistory`,

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks a lot for your prompt response. You are right, I was able to fix it based on your comments for _collectAuditTrailHistory_ but somehow I am struggeling to add this in _collectGroupMembers_. If I add a return within the loop like `return this.collectUserName(groudId, response.data.groups[0].group.members__v[i]);` than it breaks the loop and only one user is captured. Do you might have any idea how to adjust it?

Comment: I figured it out - `let promises = [];

                    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.groups[0].group.members__v.length; i++) { 
                        promises.push(this.collectUserName(groudId, response.data.groups[0].group.members__v[i]));
                    }

                    return Promise.all(promises);`

Comment: Or `return Promise.all(response.data.groups[0].group.members__v.map(member => this.collectUserName(groudId, member)));`